# Java inspection : 'for' loop replaceable with enhanced 'for'

Tags: java, loops, intellij-idea

My IntelliJ IDE gives me `'for' loop replaceable with enhanced 'for'`  warning for a loop. As I know in Java the forEach loop is a syntactic sugar.

The inspection info for that is : `Reports for loops which iterate over collections or arrays, and can be replaced with an enhanced for loop (i.e. the foreach iteration syntax)` The loop is something like below

```
        List<Object> myList = ... ;
        for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
            Object o = myList.get(i);
            // Do things with the object o
            ...
        }
```

so how is the enhanced for loop which is down below is better in this case?

```
        List<Object> myList = ... ;
        for (Object o : myList) {
            // Do things with the object o
            ...
        }
```

Comment: You don't have an extra *i* variable cluttering up your loop code.